# Checking the language of extracted trends from twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I am simply extracting top hashtags from twitter using tweepy module in python. There is one major problem I face, I wish to check if the tag in english or not. Tags that are not in english should be removed.

example:

```
tags=['AskOrange','CharlestonShooting','ReplyToASong','UberLIVE','Otecmatkasyn']
```

should not have `Otecmatkasyn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re,urllib2
def find_words(each_func):
    i=0
    wordsineach_func=[] 
    while len(each_func) >0:
        i=i+1
        word_found=longest_word(each_func)
        if len(word_found)>0:
            wordsineach_func.append(word_found)
            each_func=each_func.replace(word_found,"") 
     #   print i,word_found,each  
    return wordsineach_func       

def longest_word(phrase):
    phrase_length=len(phrase)
    words_found=[];index=0
    outerstring=""
    while index < phrase_length:
        outerstring=outerstring+phrase[index]
        index=index+1
        if outerstring in words or outerstring.lower() in words:
            words_found.append(outerstring)
    if len(words_found) ==0:
        words_found.append(phrase)
    return max(words_found, key=len)

data = urllib2.urlopen('https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-testcases/479/assets/words.txt')
words=[]
for line in data:
    words.append(line.replace("\n",""))
string="#honesthournow20"
string=string.replace("#","")
new_words=re.split(r'(\d+)',string)
output=[]
for each in new_words:
    each_words=find_words(each)
    for each_word in each_words:
        output.append(each_word)
print output
```

Then check language.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is a language detector API. A good one is the one offered by [Google](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs?csw=1), but it is not free. Another good option is [Language Detection API](https://detectlanguage.com/).

After you choose the best API for you, you'd need to parse your text so that it makes sense as a sentence. For example, the tag `'AskOrange'` must be split to read `'Ask Orange'`. You can iterate over each character of the string, check if it is uppercase and insert a space there:

```
new_tags = []
for tag in tags:
    new_word = tag
    uppercases = 0 # In case your sentence has several uppercases
    for i in xrange(1, len(tag)):
        if tag[i].istitle():
            new_word = new_word[:i+uppercases] + ' ' + new_word[i+uppercases:]
            uppercases = uppercases + 1
    new_tags.append(new_word)
```

Finally, send your list of `new_tags` to the API to detect the language.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes there are tags like `analytics2015sg`,`nypconfessions`. How to handle them?

Comment: For tags that include numbers you could split them using a similar approach as above. For example, you could also check if the character is a digit by using: `isdigit()`. For more complicated tags you could go deep into english semantics. For example, you know that english words typically do not have four or more consecutive consonants, so you can split them up. One thing for sure is that this is not a trivial problem.